# How to log an unauthenticated WebAPI call

Tags: asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application with WebAPI controllers which logs all API calls their method name, parameters and the username of the one who called it. We've done so by adding a 'DebugActionFilter' which inherits from ActionFilterAttribute. OnActionExecuting we do this logging.

This DebugActionFilter is setup in Startup.cs by this code;

[image]

This all works well, however only when the call was successfully requested, meaning authenticated. If no authentication happened or it went wrong then the API call does not get logged.

What would be a good place to implement such functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If no authentication happened or it went wrong then the API call does
> not get logged.

This is due to the authenticate operation occurred before your custom ActionFilter. Please take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#filter-types).

[image]

So it's impossible to have another filter to work before the authentication filter. By the way, do the requests which is unauthenticated is valuable to log the information for you?